# Bootstrap: Cards with icon in the top center (half outside card)

Tags: html, css

I want to replicate this layout:

[image]

What I currently have:

[image]

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/PozyYQM

Don't know why the images won't display, and there is also a button that should go in the bottom part (half outside of card).

*Code:**

```
<div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card cards-equipos">
              <img src="cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/Good-1_117x117.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">BUEN EQUIPO</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Potente máquina, con enfriamiento de aire, para el que está empezando en el mundo gaiming. 
                    Esta máquina tiene todo lo que necesitas, aunque la puedes personalizar con alguna otra pieza que te interese.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card cards-equipos">
              <img src="cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/Better-1_117x117.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">UN EQUIPO MEJOR</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Poderosa máquina con un sistema de enfriamiento líquido, ideal para los que toman
                    el gaiming como un pasatiempo serio y necesitan una performance top. Este sistema tiene todo lo que necesitas o personalizalo a tu gusto.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card cards-equipos">
              <img src="cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/Best-1_117x117.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">LO MEJOR DE LO MEJOR</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Poderosa máquina con sistema de enfriamiento líquido, ideal para 
                    quienes ven el gaiming como una profesión y quieren tener la mejor performance. Este sistema tiene
                    todo lo que necesitas o personalizalo a tu gusto.
                    Poderosa máquina con sistema de enfriamiento líquido, ideal para 
                    quienes ven el gaiming como una profesión y quieren tener la mejor performance. Este sistema tiene
                    todo lo que necesitas o personalizalo a tu gusto.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by giving the parent a `position-relative` class and the children `position-absolute`, and now we can move the children inside their parent using `top - left - right - bottom` There is how I did it.

Also as goes for the images maybe the CDN link is not valid??

[image: result]

```css
.card-deck {
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

.card-home {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/redux-bg-A-4_522x.jpg") !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.cards-icons {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5ea7eb, #438dd1);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding-top: -10%;
}

.cards-equipos {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0408/5792/7834/files/Better_400x.jpg") !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.my__img {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.custom__button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  bottom: -33px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card cards-equipos position-relative">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class=" my__img rounded-circle" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body pt-5">
      <h5 class="card-title mt-5">BUEN EQUIPO</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Potente máquina, con enfriamiento de aire, para el que está empezando en el mundo gaiming. Esta máquina tiene todo lo que necesitas, aunque la puedes personalizar con alguna otra pieza que te interese.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom__button">Primary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card cards-equipos position-relative">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class=" my__img rounded-circle" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body pt-5">
      <h5 class="card-title mt-5">BUEN EQUIPO</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Poderosa máquina con un sistema de enfriamiento líquido, ideal para los que toman el gaiming como un pasatiempo serio y necesitan una performance top. Este sistema tiene todo lo que necesitas o personalizalo a tu gusto.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom__button">Primary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card cards-equipos position-relative">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class=" my__img rounded-circle" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body pt-5">
      <h5 class="card-title mt-5">BUEN EQUIPO</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Poderosa máquina con sistema de enfriamiento líquido, ideal para quienes ven el gaiming como una profesión y quieren tener la mejor performance. Este sistema tiene todo lo que necesitas o personalizalo a tu gusto. Poderosa máquina con sistema de
        enfriamiento líquido, ideal para quienes ven el gaiming como una profesión y quieren tener la mejor performance. Este sistema tiene todo lo que necesitas o personalizalo a tu gusto.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom__button">Primary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```